# How to center a two-line text in a TextView on Android?

Tags: android, text, textview, multiline, text-alignment

I want to let it looks like this:

```
|    two    |
|   lines   |
```

Here is the current layout, not working at all.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="two\nlines"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 229, accepted):

If you just want to center it (I'm assuming the `\n` is working to split the lines), just add `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` rather than `layout_gravity`.
Using layout gravity moves the actual TextView, using gravity affects the **content** of the TextView.

Answer (score 21):

Had to add both `gravity` and `layout_gravity` to align both `TextView` and its content

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 4):

if your width is wrap_content, you have to set gravity and layout_gravity both as "center_horizontal"

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="two\nlines"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

However, if your width is "match_parent, you will only have to set gravity as "center_horizontal"

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="two\nlines"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. This works. Setting both 'gravity' and 'layout_gravity' did the trick for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the one selected is only valid with newline. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.the_text_view);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("two"+"\n"+"lines"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I use:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

to center two line text

Answer (score 1):

I think you must do it from Java:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/the_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.the_text_view);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("two<br/>lines"));
```

Answer (score -3):

Add property

```
android:lines="2"
```

where 2 is no of lines you can set this no as your requirment

Comment: this does not set the TextView centered, it only forces it to have two lines. Still, this answer is not so bad it needs to be downvoted.

Comment: It won't make any impact as requested. Alignment will not be centred.