# How do I format a TextView in a custom ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, textview

I want to show a `TextView`, placed in center of the row, be separated in two or more lines.  [image: as shown here]  but I am only able to do

[image: this].

here is my custum_adapter.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp">



   <TextView
       android:text="magnitude"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/magnitude"
       android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
   <TextView
       android:text="place"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:id="@+id/place" />

   <TextView
       android:text="date"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/date"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I want that my UI should look like the fist image.
(I have already seen this these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789550/how-to-center-a-two-line-text-in-a-textview-on-android) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258522/multiline-textview-with-width-wrap-content),  and a few others but none could answer mine)

**EDIT:** I have asked about formatting the data in a custom `ListView` when there are more than  two items in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `RelativeLayout` you could just use a horizontal `LinearLayout` with the appropriate `layout_weight` attributes.

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magnitude"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="magnitude"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="place"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="date"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to this hope this can help you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magnitude"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:text="magnitude"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="place"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="date"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use weights with linearLayout. It'll solve your problem and they will **never overlap**. copy paste the code below. You can change the value of weights according to your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/magnitude"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="magnitude"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".6"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="place weifjn eiunf indfg dkjmvd jdfokjdfodf"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="date"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work For You :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- row.xml -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"


        <TextView
           android:text="magnitude"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:gravity="center"
           android:id="@+id/magnitude"
           android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
           android:textSize="15sp"
          />

        <TextView
           android:text="place"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0.4"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:inputType="textMultiLine"
           android:textSize="15sp"
           android:id="@+id/place" />

        <TextView
           android:text="date"
           android:inputType="textMultiLine"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0.4"
           android:id="@+id/date"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:textSize="15sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```